# Filtrar respuesta de MySql con NodeJs

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, express, filtro

Estoy tratando de filtrar unos usuarios donde hago dos consultas a la base de datos. Por lo que `results` es la respuesta con recoje todos los contactos del usuario y en la otra respuesta se guardan los contactos que pertenecen al grupo que paso por parametro.

Quiero devolver una respuesta con los contactos que no formen parte del grupo, es decir, la respuesta seria `results` quitandole los que aparezcan en `results1`. Pero me devuelve un `array` vacio.

```
let data = results.filter(elem => {
        let res = results1.find(user => {
            return user.user_id !== elem.user_id
        });
 });
```

Estructura de `results` y `results1`:

```
[
  TextRow {
        id: 22,
        user_id: 53,
  },
  TextRow {
        id: 234,
        user_id: 193,
  }
]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que obtienes en las dos consultas?, para ver la estructura de lo que quieres filtar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, debes asegurarte de que lo que quieres trabajar sea un array de objetos *planos*, es decir, que no sean instancias de clases, esto para poder trabajarlos después. Si te das cuenta en tus resultados la palabra `TextRow` se hace presente en cada uno de tus resultados. Esto quiere decir que tienes arrays de TextRow's. Tomando como referencia [está respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object) del sitio homónimo en inglés, lo que podrías hacer para "pre-procesar" la información sería algo como esto:

```javascript
results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Con eso la estructura de tus resultados debería pasar a esto:

```javascript
[
  {
    id: 22,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    user_id: 193
  }
];
```

Y ahora podrás hacer el filtrado utilizando [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) y [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let result = [
  {
    id: 20,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    user_id: 193
  }
];

let result1 = [
  {
    id: 20,
    user_id: 53
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    user_id: 53
  }
];

const filtered = result.reduce((acc, r) => {
  // Buscar r dentro de r1
  const index = result1.findIndex((r1) => {
    return r1.id === r.id;
  });

  // Si no se encuentra (-1) entonces se agrega a los resultados
  if (index === -1) {
    acc.push(r);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log("filtered", filtered);
```

Comment: De esta manera me devuelve los contactos de ese grupo `r1.id === r.id`, por lo que para conseguir los que no son de ese grupo deberia de ser `r1.id !== r.id` pero me devuelve todos los contacos, es decir,  los de `results`

Comment: Vale, creo que olvidé ese detalle, pero solo para confirmar. ¿Quieres retornar los elementos de `r` que no se encuentren en `r1`?

Comment: Puedes ver la actualización de mi pregunta por favor.

Comment: Genial, si te sirvió la respuesta recuerda aceptarla como correcta, o en su defecto, agregar tu solución y márcala como respuesta correcta.